# spring-boot-batch-test: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Spring-batch is looking for datasource in test context, even if I don't use any DB connection neither in test context nor in application context.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:276) ~[spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> ... 71 more

**Test class:**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext.ClassMode;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener;

@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Scheduler.class })
@ComponentScan
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:calculator-test.properties")
public class CalculatorTest {
    @Autowired private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    @Autowired private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;
    @Test
    public void test_end_to_end() throws Exception {
            final JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
            Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }
}
```

**Configuration class:**

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
class Scheduler {
    @Autowired private JobBuilderFactory jbf;
    @Autowired private StepBuilderFactory sbf;
    @Bean Tasklet tasklet1() { return new TaskletCalculateDivision(); }
    @Bean Tasklet tasklet2() { return new TaskletCalculateAddition(); }
    @Bean Step step1() { return sbf.get("Division").tasklet(tasklet1()).build(); }
    @Bean Step step2() { return sbf.get("Addition").tasklet(tasklet2()).build(); }
    @Bean Job job() { return jbf.get("Calculate").start(step1()).next(step2()).build(); }   
}
```

I try to apply unit tests on spring-batch steps.

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3767) deals with the same topic. As per my understanding, the fix is only available on spring 5.

Comment: This was fixed in Spring Batch 5, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4070.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, Thank you for your answer. However I'm looking for a workaround for 2.7.2 version.

Comment: With v4, you need to provide a datasource (you could use an embedded one for tests).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine It's working! Many thanks. I added `@DataJpaTest`
and `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` in my test class. Also `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `h2` artifacts in pom.xml.

Comment: `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` is not finally required.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, I'm now facing `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? ` issue. This [post](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17536) suggests 2 ways to resolve that. I persoanlly prefer `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` solution. However, when I added it on both **calculator-test.properties** and **application-test.properties** it still not working. Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Is there any miss from my end to make `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` working? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't run and debug the code you shared, but this error means the test database is not initialized with Spring Batch tables. This should be done by Spring Boot automatically, otherwise, you need to initialize the database yourself if needed.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, Thank you for your reply. What you suggest is the second option described in the post that i share above. I try that and be back to let my feedback.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, Finally I put sql scripts in **schema.sql** and **data.sql** files likes is described in the second option of the above post.
Moreover, I was brought to create some sequences for thos table creation scripts.
Now everything is working with spring-boot-2.7.2. I consider that this topic is resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `@SpringBatchTest` annotation in your tests you must have a data source bean in your class path. This is because part of the spring batch design there are a few tables that will store batch execution information. This is build in spring-batch itself.

Please have a read of [Spring Batch documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index.html)

From there under JobRepository section:

*Other than the dataSource and the transactionManager, none of the configuration options listed earlier are required.*

Comment: Hi Julian, Thank you for your answer. In fact, I don't want to use DataSource. If I remove  `@SpringBatchTest` annotation how spring injects `jobLauncherTestUtils` and `jobRepositoryTestUtils` in context test to trigger my jobs?
From other hand, documentation is up to date. It concerns spring 5 wich requires JDK17. In my case I'm using spring 2.7.2 which requires JDK1.8. Upgrade JDK from 1.8 to 17 it's not yet campany policy

Comment: I would not call it a "fix" but rather a "feature", which I was not aware of. Providing you cannot use Java 17 to get around this I can see two ways: 1. In the text context provide a mock DataSource bean or 2. use an embedded database such as H2 in the test context. Both those Utils classes use a `JobRepository` bean which in turn uses some DAO beans which in turn use a `JdbcTemplate` so not having a DataSource available will hard or not possible. Even in the link you provided they resolved this by creating a `NullDataSource` mock. You can look at their source code and inspire or just create 1

Comment: I call it a fix because it sounds more than a defeact than a new enhancement.
1. Maybe providing a mock DataSource sounds a good solution. However I don't know yet how to implement it. 2. Using H2 let believe that a DataSource is really required by the application which is not the case. 3. Creating a NullDataSource may not be simple because this probably needs to redefine some other classes in spring framework.
I try the first solution and I let my feedback on this in order to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a better solution. I resolved the issue by :

1. Adding **h2** maven dependency.
2. In **Schedule.java**, I added the bellow code:

`@Bean DataSource getDataSource() { return DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName("org.h2.Driver").url("jdbc:h2:mem:AZ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE").username("user1").password("pass").build(); }`